# Get list of users in a role using JBoss with Active Directory

Tags: java, jboss, active-directory

If I have a JBoss server which connects to an Active Directory Server using the LdapExtLoginModule, is it possible for my java restful web servlet to take in the name of a Group in Active Directory as a String, and ask the Active Directory Server for a list of Users which are a part of that Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. The hard way would be to use JNDI to do an LDAP query for all users (objectCategory=person) with the attribute member=. But JNDI is not the most elegant API, finding an AD server properly is not trivial and you would have to do everything using DN strings and not the usual Windows names.

The easy way would be to use Jespa which makes this sort of thing almost trivial, it will fail-over to another AD server properly and it understands Windows group names, account names, SIDs and so on. Jespa also does a lot of other stuff. If you're ultimately trying to check group membership and you use the Jespa NtlmSecurityProvider for auth instead, you can check group membership using Account.isMemberOf (or isUserInRole) and it's MUCH quicker than doing LDAP.